# Write GAMS results in text file

Tags: gams-math

Why is it that GAMS stores results in file with .put extension though i made new project in working directory and specified `file  mse /D:\RS Results\mse_goal(0.5).txt/;
put mse;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
parameter x /1/;
file  mse /D:\mse_goal(0.5).txt/;
put mse;

put
'The value of x ='x
```

Note that GAMS may not like spaces in filepathnames ("D:\RS Results")